# Creating a neutral

Tags: transformer

I have been using a delta star isolation transformer on a VSD to create a neutral. Is it possible to use a an auto transformer to create a neutral?
Is there a cheaper way to create a neutral apart from using a transformer?

Comment: More details needed. Why do you need a neutral and what are you going to use it for?

Comment: I use a neutral to run single phase devices

Comment: You need the isolation of a transformer to allow you to reference the output from neutral. An auto transformer is not suitable. There may be other means to obtain a single phase output referenced to neutral, but a transformer is the simplest and most effective means of doing this. Tesla thought so.

Answer (score 1):

There are transformers which are just a Y with no isolation. The star point develops a neutral. If the three phase is relatively balanced, the power rating only needs to be big enough for the neutral current, not the full load.

I've used such a transformer in a phase converter, where the motor was delta only.

You can also get a neutral from a star fed motor, again handy with phase converters.